EXCEL Sumproduct COUNT 2 AND condition every nth COLUMN, counting blank and not blank
Good Day  to all! as my title suggest I am having a problem with the sumproduct formula to get the result that for the following condition

Check and Count every 4th column range for NOT blank starting column B
Check and Count Every 4th column range for IS BLANK starting column D
Final Result: Count the number of cell where the Order Label Not Blank and Amount Label Blank condition is both satisfied
Note there is 1 blank column gap every column label for spacing
Individually the formula works but if i try to combine the formula to consolidate it, it does not work anymore
simplified the sample sheet but actual data has more columns but same case and setup of every nth column

working count Not blank formula every 4th column from starting column
=SUMPRODUCT(--((MOD(COLUMN($B$2:$H$3)-COLUMN(B2),4)=0)*NOT(ISBLANK($B$2:$H$3))))

working count blank formula every 4th column from starting column
=SUMPRODUCT(--((MOD(COLUMN($D$2:$H$3)-COLUMN(D2),4)=0)*(ISBLANK($D$2:$H$3))))

my code when i Combine the 2 codes but not working N/A Error or sometime VALUE error if I play around with the ( ) bracketing
=SUMPRODUCT(
--((MOD(COLUMN($B$2:$H$3)-COLUMN(B2),4)=0)*NOT(ISBLANK($B$2:$H$3)))
*--((MOD(COLUMN($D$2:$H$3)-COLUMN(D2),4)=0)*(ISBLANK($D$2:$H$3)))
)

please see sample screenshot for reference.
sample expected data and result
Thank You!

There is nothing wrong it is supposed to return an error, both matrixes are not of same size. To make it work why not increase the second MOD() to up till J3? Like this : =SUM(--((MOD(COLUMN($B$2:$H$3)-COLUMN(B2),4)=0)*NOT(ISBLANK($B$2:$H$3)))*--((MOD(COLUMN($D$2:$J$3)-COLUMN(D2),4)=0)*(ISBLANK($D$2:$J$3)))) or if you dont want to expand then use EXPAND() function : =SUM(--((MOD(COLUMN($B$2:$H$3)-COLUMN(B2),4)=0)*NOT(ISBLANK($B$2:$H$3)))*EXPAND(--((MOD(COLUMN($D$2:$H$3)-COLUMN(D2),4)=0)*(ISBLANK($D$2:$H$3))),,7,0))

@MayukhBhattacharya ty for pointing out the cause of the error I tried both your solutions and it works especially the expand formula which i learned from you. My question is if I insist on sumproduct formula with expand how would it look like ?
I tried to change my current sumproduct code and adjusting the range to make it same size but the error is still there.
=SUMPRODUCT(
--((MOD(COLUMN($B$2:$H$3)-COLUMN(B2),4)=0)*NOT(ISBLANK($B$2:$J$3)))
*--((MOD(COLUMN($D$2:$H$3)-COLUMN(D2),4)=0)*(ISBLANK($D$2:$J$3)))
)


Nope I dont get that error on expanding and the reason is my I and J columns are empty while for you it could be there are some values for each it is returning an error or something. Also I just it should still work even if there are any values. it still returns me 1, could you show me a screenshot where you are getting the error. See its self explanatory even you can see, the first mod has 7 columns while the second one has 5, so there is a short of 2, you need to ensure to make them both sizes to make it work

@MayukhBhattacharya done :) ty I found the error with the bracketing and it showed the expected result.  Appreciate you gave the solution and explanation as well
How can i check your answer to mark it as solved, it does not show on mine,
I can mark Balazs answer but not yours,

sure so you can get points :P

Nevermind if you want to go ahead with other users solution then its no use of posting otherwise, whatever suits you best, getting points is not big deal, making users understand what they are trying to do.

Ty good sir!  I wish you good karma  for your help
